# Compile cxx files in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, objective-c++

I am new at IPHone development , I included a library with .cxx as implementation class and a .h header but still i get error at compiling , Please any help?
I get errors at lines like below

```
class StackEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Objective-C class that is including any C or C++ code must be renamed with a ".mm" suffix rather than ".m" in the implementation class.

Comment: It is renamed to .mm .... but still it doesnt work ...
Compilier suggests that i change class to Class

Comment: But I include the C++ header in the Objective C header , when i include it in .mm it works ... but i need to include it in the header

Comment: Did you change all the files that reference that header to .mm too? i.e., if you need to include the .cxx file in "Foobar.h", every single file that includes "Foobar.h" will have to change to .mm

Answer (score 0):

Any Objective-C file (.m) that includes any header containing C++ code, either directly or by chained #includes, will likely fail with compile errors.

You need to rename all your .m files to .mm if they can "see" your C++ header.

If that causes too much renaming, then you'll have to limit your #includes, for example by take the C++ #include out of your header file and putting it only in the .mm files that need it.